# Set a dropdown list value = url parameter

Tags: laravel, get, laravel-blade

Trying to pass a value from one route to another, however i'm trying to set a dropdown value = to the parameter i'm passing via the URL.

For example:

```
<a href="/job?type=web_dev">GO</a>
```

Then on `/job?type=web_dev`

```
<select name="job" id="job">
  <option value="web_dev">Web Dev</option>
  <option value="soft_engine">Software Engineer</option>
  <option value="marketing">Marketing</option>
</select>
```

Id like the selected value to be in this case = web_dev.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `URL` is like `example.com/job?type=web_dev`

In your view, you can do:

```
    <select name="job" id="job">
       <option @if(Input::get('type')=='web_dev') selected @endif value="web_dev> Web Dev </option>
       <option @if(Input::get('type')=='soft_engine') selected @endif value="soft_engine> Web Dev </option>
       <option @if(Input::get('type')=='marketing') selected @endif value="marketing> Web Dev </option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Thanks all I had to do was replace `Input` with `Request`.

Comment: With the current Laravel, you can use the `request()` helper method also. So it would be `@if(request()->get('type')=='web_dev') selected @endif`

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 5.7 you can do:

```
{{ Request()->type == 'web_dev' ? ' selected' : '' }}
```